# Access Variable Defines in .m file for Unit Testing Objective-C XCTest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I am using XCTestKit for unit testing in my app using Objective-C.
I need to test the default values of textfields on my screen but the IBOutlets are declared under .m file.

Is there any way to access those variables, or any other approach to test the values in UnitTest classes.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem. Please show some example code.

Comment: You can access those values with Key Value Observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your .m file has something like

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

One approach is to expose this in your test file like this by copying and pasting **to your test file,** but giving the category a name:

```
@interface MyClass (Testing)
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

- The advantage of this approach is it keeps the outlet hidden from your -public interface.
- The disadvantage is that the duplication means if you change anything about the property declaration, you have to remember to repeat it in your test file.

Another approach is to move your outlet from your .m to your .h.

- The advantage of this approach is that it acknowledges that testing is a valid client of your API, and avoids duplication.
- The disadvantage of this approach is that you will have more in your API than you want all clients to know.

I prefer the second approach. What I do then is soften the disadvantage by not treating the class interface as the "interface for everybody". Instead, I split things off into protocols, exposing only what particular clients need for *their* interactions alone.

Comment: Thanks for replying Jon but creating another file will not be good for future making changes in original file will never impact on test cases

Comment: I am not talking about making another file. You can take either approach with your existing files.

Comment: ok so adding  (Testing) will work you saying ? let me check with this

Comment: Just to be clear: that's how you can copy and paste your outlet _to your test file_. The name "Testing" doesn't matter at all, it just needs a name.